# Do we have any tool to convert Android xml layout to .java files?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have my layout files in XML. But I want to create my views programatically in my Java code. Are there any tools to convert XML layout files into the equivalent Java code?

Answer (score 11):

you can try:

[xmltojava.com Mirror 1](http://www.xmltojava.com)

[xmltojava.com Mirror 2](http://37.46.125.53/xmltojava/)

> This service provides an automatic conversion of Android XML codes
>   (tags and Attributes) to equivalent Android Java methods. All you need
>   is some XML code and you are good to go.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @MartínMarconcini - check the 2nd link

Comment: saved me a ton of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`LayoutInflater.inflate` is used to create view hierarchies from xml files. But I am not aware of any tool that can convert xml files to equivalent java code. Hopefully, it's a one time job and you can do it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Been a couple years since the original question... but I did locate a completely free open source project!  It is designed as a plugin for Android Studio (IntelliJ) or Eclipse. There are two different projects... http://tmorcinek.github.io/android-codegenerator-plugin-intellij/ Android-codegenerator-plugin-intellij - I tested it on the current Android Studio 1.2 beta and it does create Java code from XML layout files.

Answer (score 1):

try this [XML to java](http://www.xmltojava.com/). not the best but you can try, i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above http://tmorcinek.github.io/android-codegenerator-plugin-intellij/ works perfect to create android Java code form xml layout. You can create Activity,Fragment, Custom adapter and even Butter Knife versions of the same using this. Its super awesome. You can install it from Plugins -> Browse Repository ->Android code generator->Install .
Happy Coding